# Problem dumping infos correctly in JSON file in python

Tags: python, json, discord.py

I have a code that dumps every username from my discord server in a JSON file but some characters make it work in a weird way, I have something to check if an username is already in the JSON file and if it is it doesn't add the said username, but some characters somehow bypass this and usernames get added multiple time in my JSON file, this is the code I use (detailed as much as possible for better understanding):

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext import tasks
import json
from datetime import date

@tasks.loop(minutes=30)
async def autoUpdateDB():
    count = 0 #keep count about how many people got added to the JSON file
    debugchannel = bot.get_channel(1134732572816068628) #channel where the bot will send a message
    with open("prevname.json", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        users = json.load(f)

    with open("cleared.json", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        cleared = json.load(f)

    for guild in bot.guilds:
        for members in guild.members:
            currentDate = date.today() #get today's date
            usersid = members.id #get members' id
            names = members.name #get members' names
            displayname = members.display_name #get members' display name
            if str(usersid) in users: #if member's id not in the JSON file
                if names not in str(cleared): #if member's name not in 2nd JSON file
                    if names not in str(users[str(usersid)]): #if member's name not in JSON file in "id":{}
                        users[str(usersid)].append({f"{currentDate}": names}) #add name to users
                        count = count + 1
                        with open("prevname.json", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
                            json.dump(users, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4) #write users in JSON file

            else:
                if names not in str(cleared): #if member's name not in 2nd JSON file
                    users[str(usersid)] = [{f"{currentDate}": names}] #add name to users
                    count = count + 1
                    with open("prevname.json", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
                        json.dump(users, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4) #write users in JSON file
```

I tried to google my problem but nothing seems to solve it so my last resort is to post my problem on here, if something feels unclear ask me I'll gladly give further informations about my problem, thanks in advance.

Comment: Which type of usernames are we talking about? Do you have a concrete example that we can look at?

Comment: yeah sure, there's a guy with invisible characters set as his username and he gets added everytime: "2023-08-07": "᲼᲼᲼᲼ ᲼᲼᲼᲼ ᲼᲼᲼᲼᲼᲼ ᲼᲼᲼᲼ ᲼᲼᲼᲼ ᲼᲼᲼᲼᲼"

Comment: Maybe these characters are not UTF-8, but your json file is converting it to UTF-8. So, you must encode your `names` string as UTF-8 before comparing it with the json loaded data.

Comment: I already tried doing that and it said it failed encoding some names because they were only ascii with some utf-8 char

Comment: @schizophrenic Have you tried `names = members.name.decode('utf-8', 'ignore')` ? This way you are telling Python to ignore portions of a string that it can't convert to utf-8

Comment: nope, I haven't tried that, let me try and tell you if it works

Comment: it gives me this error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'